# Passing array pointer in C and Swiping Values from Different Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, swap

This application is supposed to swap the first three numbers of the array using function below. The code works when I swap numbers like 1 2 3 4 5, but when I tried to use this number 5 3 4 9 8 7 2 it does not display the right output. I really can not find what is wrong with the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int a_lenth, i,a_content;
    printf("Enter the lenth of the array:");
    scanf("%d", &a_lenth);
    int arr[a_lenth];
    int arr2[a_lenth];

    for(i = 0; i < a_lenth; i++){
            printf("Enter the elements of the array:");
            scanf("%d", &a_content);
            arr[i] = a_content;
            arr2[i] = a_content;
    };

    roll(arr, a_content, arr2);

    return 0;
}

void roll(int *a1, int n, int *a2){
    int e;

    a2[0] = a1[2];
    a2[1] = a1[0];
    a2[2] = a1[1];


    for(e = 0; e < n; e++){
            printf("%d\n", a2[e]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of a_content in this call roll(arr, a_content, arr2);

Comment: a_content is the variable that gets the value from the user and stores it on the arrays  arr[0] = a_content.

Comment: Reread my question one more if one time is not enough to understand it.

Comment: If I understood correctly, n is supposed to be the length of the array. Then why is the function call `roll` done with `a_content`? Shouldn't it be done with `a_lenth` ?

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment :

The call to the function roll expects second argument to be number of elements int array, but the one you are sending is `a_content` (A trivial mistake I suppose)

Changing it to : `roll(arr, a_lenth, arr2);`

Input : ( The one specified in the question)

```
Enter the lenth of the array:7
Enter the elements of the array:5
Enter the elements of the array:3
Enter the elements of the array:4
Enter the elements of the array:9
Enter the elements of the array:8
Enter the elements of the array:7
Enter the elements of the array:2
```

Output :

```
4
5
3
9
8
7
2
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I could not believe that I made that simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This would do what you need. As pointed out before roll is called incorrectly because a_content isn't the length of your output array.

```
int main(void){

    int a_length;
    int a_content;
    printf("Enter the lenth of the array:");
    scanf("%d", &a_length);
    int arr1[a_length];
    int arr2[a_length];

    for(int i = 0; i < a_length; i++){
        printf("Enter the elements of the array:");
        scanf("%d", &a_content);
        arr1[i] = a_content;
        arr2[i] = a_content;
    };

    //void roll(int *a1, int n, int *a2) where n == a_length
    arr2[0] = arr1[2];
    arr2[1] = arr1[0];
    arr2[2] = arr1[1];

    for(int e = 0; e < a_length; e++){
        printf("%d\n", arr2[e]);
    }

return 0;
}
```